# A friendly reminder to all meta users: your perfect is the enemy of the community's good enough

Tags: discussion, meta, psa

Scenario:

- A question about something that should be changed/fixed on Stack Overflow is asked on Meta
- I post an answer with a suggestion that will handle 99% of the cases the question is relevant to.
- Meta users post comments on my answer, suggesting it is problematic because it doesn't consider or cover the particular special case they've thought of.

**I.

KNOW.**

That's the whole purpose of the answer, to fix the problem for the 99%. We can handle the special cases specially!

This fixation by some members on finding a "perfect" solution for *every conceivable possibility* is **harming** the community, because it results in good possible solutions for the 99% being ignored and/or downvoted, and hence discarded, simply because said solutions don't work for their 1% case. With the end result that **no** solution gets implemented, because none of them are perfect.

If you work in software development, you should already know that [perfect is the enemy of good enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good). Please use logic, and approach Meta questions the same way. Think about what would help the community first and foremost, not what will solve *your* particular problem.

Comment: "I. KNOW." Then acknowledge those shortcomings in your answer. When I pitch a 80% solution at work, I write down all of the pros and cons of my solution, showing how it solves 80% of the problem, and how we'll deal with the 20% of the problem later or in another way.

Comment: Ah yes, the "my answers getting downvoted is harming the community" argument. When your answer can't even get enough upvotes to counter the few downvotes of the "pedantic users", then why do you think your answer is good?

Comment: As stated, this seems too broad. I have no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: "*Please use logic, and approach Meta questions the same way.*"  Some readers may see this as condescending.

Comment: You do have a point. But have you considered that when excluding the 1% of one scenario, you can end up excluding everything by just adding scenarios. And how do you know the solution works for 99%, and not 51%?

Comment: @Scratte I agree, that's the key! The so-called "1%" may actually be much larger than that, and we'll never know without the discussion and back and forth.

Comment: @IanKemp Sometimes the community disagrees with you. Sometimes the disagreement will seem illogical or even harmful. If a comment isn't useful to you but isn't flaggable, the only thing you can do is ignore it. (You can always delete an answer if it's getting a lot of annoying engagement.) But I don't think you're going to get a lot of traction with, "Please don't disagree with me in this specific way".

Comment: I hate to bring this news to you: There is no logic on Meta. That is just an opinion.

Comment: I just want to make sure I follow. You advocate for the community and its best interests, but the meta-netizens who vote do not?

Comment: IanKemp: you need to illustrate with specific examples from Meta, in principle you're not wrong but this is way too vague, also will collapse under a morass of subjective and dismissive responses. I've personally had cases where I'd entirely agree with you, but also the opposite. It probably also matters whether the specifics of *"don't work for the other 1%"* could mean (by analogy to SO) "corrupt your database/trash your install" or just "error out with a clear message teling you why it's not applicable" or "are so self-evidently inapplicable that you'd never even code them up"

Answer (score 25):

> Meta users post comments on my answer, suggesting it is problematic because it doesn't consider or cover the particular special case they've thought of.

Counter-point: While this can certainly be frustrating, this is *also* the way that a good suggestion can become great—by building on top of it.

On the Meta site, a certain amount of discussion is permitted, even though it breaks the strict Q&A model. The reason we allow this is because the community is actually pretty good at working together to figure out exemplary solutions to hard problems.

Your 90 or 99% idea often forms the basis for a 100% idea, with some tweaks by others, who may have thought of things that you haven't, spurred on by your having gotten over the initial hump.

When giving support-style answers, it's almost impossible to cover every edge case, because there are so many of them. I often don't even try. I do appreciate when others come along and fill in the gaps. Especially if it makes them happy. :-)

Comment: "Your 90 or 99% idea often forms the basis for a 100% idea" that sounds like early optimizations. :D